# Weird SQL Issue with Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am currently in the process of building an API for an application and am having some trouble with a particular query.

This is my original query:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, 
       unclaimed_users.id AS unclaimed_id, 
       `users`.`firstname`, 
       `users`.`lastname`, 
       `unclaimed_users`.`mobile_number`, 
       `group_members`.`status`, 
       `user_images`.`profile_image_main` 
FROM   `group_members` 
       LEFT JOIN `users` 
              ON `users`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
                 AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `user_images` 
              ON `user_images`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
                 AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 0 
       LEFT JOIN `unclaimed_users` 
              ON `unclaimed_users`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
                 AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 1 
WHERE  `group_members`.`group_id` = 1 
ORDER  BY `group_members`.`created_at` ASC
```

When I execute the above query, I am receiving the two records I expect, however, any field extracted from the `unclaimed_user` table is returning an empty string (not null), instead of returning the value.

See here:

```
+------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------+--------------------+
| id   | unclaimed_id | firstname | lastname | mobile_number | status  | profile_image_main |
+------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------+--------------------+
|    1 |         NULL | Ben       | Carey    | NULL          | active  | NULL               |
| NULL |            0 | NULL      | NULL     |               | pending | NULL               |
+------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------+--------------------+
```

However, when I replace the `SELECT` with `SELECT *`, it returns all the fields expected, with the expected values. For instance `mobile_number` returns the mobile number associated with the relevant unclaimed user.

What am I doing wrong? I cannot work out is happening and why the values are not being returned.

I have tried removing all the fields and only including one field from the unclaimed users table e.g.

`SELECT unclaimed_users.id FROM etc...`

The above returned 0, but it should return 1...

It is important to note that both `id` and `mobile_number` are present on the `users` table and the `unclaimed_users` table.

### Update

I am currently in the process of putting a fiddle together but it is proving harder than I thought as I am yet to successfully recreate the issue...

In the meantime, I have simplified the query which is still not returning what it is meant to:

```
SELECT `unclaimed_users`.`mobile_number` 
FROM   `group_members` 
       LEFT JOIN `unclaimed_users` 
              ON `unclaimed_users`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
                 AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 1 
WHERE  `group_members`.`group_id` = 1
```

The above returns the following

```
+---------------+
| mobile_number |
+---------------+
| NULL          |
|               |
+---------------+
```

When it **should** return:

```
+---------------+
| mobile_number |
+---------------+
| NULL          |
| +447777779999 |
+---------------+
```

If I replace the `SELECT unclaimed_users.mobile_number` with `SELECT *`, the correct data is returned so the join is working. I cannot see why I am unable to reference the field `mobile_number`

### Update 2

I have noticed that it works when I execute the following:

```
SELECT `unclaimed_users`.`mobile_number` 
FROM   `group_members` 
       LEFT JOIN `unclaimed_users` 
              ON `unclaimed_users`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
                 AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 1 
WHERE  `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 1 -- This is the bit I changed
```

Because the above is ignoring the first record in the table (the one where `unclaimed_user=0`, it seems to work...

Comment: You might have more success if you provide a sample working fiddle with your issue.   At minimum, sample data and expected results would be helpful though.

Comment: @sgeddes I didn't realise an SQL fiddle website actually existed... I am currently in the process of building an example but I am struggling to recreate the issue

Comment: @sgeddes I am really struggling to create the fiddle and replicating the issue. I have updated my question with results and expected results, would you mind taking a look? I have noticed something that may make this very simple to solve, see my latest update

Comment: You maybe have some wrong data in your tables, e.g. some default empty users. Check for users with `user_id=0` in `group_members` and `id=0` in `unclaimed_users`, this (or one of these) will probably be the one with the empty-but-not-null mobile number, and you get them in your results even if you don't expect them (and think you would get something different). Print the unique primary key of your `unclaimed_users`-table (if you have one) in your queries, it might be different in your different results.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide too much to test...

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, 
   unclaimed_users.id AS unclaimed_id, 
   `users`.`firstname`, 
   `users`.`lastname`, 
   `unclaimed_users`.`mobile_number`, 
   `group_members`.`status`,
   `group_members`.`user_id`,
   `group_members`.`unclaimed_user`,
   `user_images`.`profile_image_main` 
FROM   `group_members` 
   LEFT JOIN `users` 
          ON `users`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
             AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 0 
   LEFT JOIN `user_images` 
          ON `user_images`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
             AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 0 
   LEFT JOIN `unclaimed_users` 
          ON `unclaimed_users`.`id` = `group_members`.`user_id` 
             AND `group_members`.`unclaimed_user` = 1 
WHERE  `group_members`.`group_id` = 1 
ORDER  BY `group_members`.`created_at` ASC
```

I'm not sure if a good answer, I just can't add a comment.

Comment: Please can you highlight what the difference is?

Comment: Did it make any change? I just tried to add in a explicit way the two columns you are using for the join. I'm not sure if MySQL does it have them during the execution. I'm not sure how it reads the sentences, if from down to up and right to left.

Comment: No, it didnt make any difference other than return a few extra fields...

Comment: lol right, that has sense, can you create a fiddle to ilustrate better your issue? Use this site for example http://sqlfiddle.com/